# Sparkle checkForUpdatesInBackground places no request on webserver

Tags: objective-c, sparkle

In my command-line application, when calling `[[SUUpdater sharedUpdater] checkForUpdatesInBackground]`, project Sparkle does not place an HTTPS request on my webserver. I want a call to `checkForUpdatesInBackground` to succeed, so I know my setup is right. I am using an Nginx webserver over HTTPS, and view the logs of this server to make sure the appcast.xml file is being requested.

I have tried debugging the Sparkle framework, and found out after calling `checkForUpdatesInBackground`, the framework does call `dispatch_async` in [here](https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/blob/80d8758fc22e213993e23b60f9fc82c70570b73c/Sparkle/SPUDownloaderSession.m#L58). This gave the following stack trace.

```
2018-12-20 06:46:46.037297-0800 MyApplication[28705:224144] Stack trace : (
0   ???                                 0x00000001005a7b0e 0x0 + 4300897038
1   MyApplication                       0x0000000100001af0 main + 0
2   Sparkle                             0x000000010036a5f9 -[SUAppcast fetchAppcastFromURL:inBackground:completionBlock:] + 1625
3   Sparkle                             0x0000000100372fff -[SUBasicUpdateDriver checkForUpdatesAtURL:host:] + 1423
4   Sparkle                             0x00000001003aabe5 -[SUUpdater checkForUpdatesWithDriver:] + 773
5   Sparkle                             0x00000001003aa41e -[SUUpdater checkForUpdatesInBackground] + 494
6   MyApplication                       0x0000000100001b9f main + 175
7   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5ddd1085 start + 1
)
```

My Info.plist:

```
{
"SUAllowsAutomaticUpdates" = NO;
CFBundleIconFile = "myicon.icns";
CFBundleExecutable = MyApplication;
"SUAutomaticallyUpdate" = NO;
"SUScheduledCheckInterval" = 3600;
"SUEnableAutomaticChecks" = NO;
SUPublicEDKey = "0xe+xaH4VBOMIADOqOqBAZug/hnrCqBKUyCffx+8Qvw=";
SUFeedURL = "https://test.myurl.com/appcast.xml";
CFBundleVersion = "1.0.0.0";
"CFBundleShortVersionString" = "7.0";
CFBundleIdentifier = "nl.apps.myapp";
}
```

My Code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [[SUUpdater sharedUpdater] checkForUpdatesInBackground];
    }
}
```

Sparkle does halt the termination of my application in order to wait for the request to end. On my webserver I do not see the appcast.xml being requested, and Sparkle does not show a window with any update information.

Comment: You say this is a command-line application? Because Sparkle is designed to work from within a Cocoa app; I can't image how it would function inside a tool. I can think of a half-dozen reasons this won't work, the first being that you don't appear to have a main run loop, which all Cocoa apps depend on. If there's a solution to this, it would be simply create an HTTP request, query your sparkle RSS feed data, decode it using XML, and look at the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, like [Rengers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243192/rengers) pointed out, Sparkle does not work because it is a command-line tool. This means there exists no main loop where Sparkle depends on. Sparkle places some of its actions on the main event queue using [dispatch_async](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1453057-dispatch_async), for example [here](https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/blob/80d8758fc22e213993e23b60f9fc82c70570b73c/Sparkle/SPUDownloaderSession.m#L58) in the source code.

To overcome this, I've made my command-line tool into a GUI, and now it all works fine.